# How can I get JavaScript Cookie in android Java code?

Tags: javascript, java, android, cookies

I have write cookie in JavaScript

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue){
   window.localStorage.setItem(cname, JSON.stringify(cvalue));
}

setCookie('test_cookie',123);


function getCookie(cname) {
    var cookieValue = window.localStorage.getItem(cname);
    if (cookieValue) {
        return JSON.parse(cookieValue);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

getCookie('test_cookie'); //Output 123
```

I have generate one cookie name is `test_cookie` and value is `123` I need to get this `123` cookie value in Java code.

How to get my cookie value in Android Java?

Comment: How are you accessing the page ? i.e Apache `HttpClient` ? or `HttpUrlConnection` ? or something else ?

Comment: This snippet goes in an Applet? Or an javaFX application? Do you have any wrapper class?

Comment: I don't know.  I am using phonegap

Answer (score 0):

This question might answer your problems.

[Communication between Android Java and Phonegap Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727763/communication-between-android-java-and-phonegap-javascript)

You'll need to add a JavascriptInterface.

Answer (score 0):

you can find your answer [here-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622374/javascript-document-cookie-in-android)

```
yourWebViewVariable.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

for Android 3.1 just add this to your java file onLoadInit:

```
CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true); //This is the line that    
specifically makes it work so the other lines is optional

CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();      
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true); cookieManager.acceptCookie();
```